# Performance improvements when using mutable StatelessWidgets over StatefulWidgets

Tags: flutter, performance, dart

Recently I've been getting into using `StreamBuilders` and `ValueListenableBuilder` over rebuilding the whole tree using `setState`. And this got me wondering whether there is a performance improvement over using these state mechanisms in a "mutable" `StatelessWidget` instead of a `StatefulWidget`.

Though, I've been doing some testing with rebuilds and callers to assess whether there is a difference between hoisting those states on the class (with `StatefulWidget` and mutable `StatelessWidget`) and putting the callers inside `(Stream|ValueListenable)Builder` (on immutable `StatelessWidget`), but arrived to the conclusion they call the exact same times, and rebuild the exact same way.

I understand this would not be the case if the widget itself is nested under another `(Stream|ValueListenable)Builder` that changes to its state, but I'm wondering whether there is a difference between depending on a `StatefulWidget` that does not call `setState` in its lifetime and a `StatelessWidget` that cannot have `const` in its constructor due to hoisting. (As per performance best practices, 2nd point 3rd sub: https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/best-practices)

TLDR: Is there a benefit to choose a `StatelessWidget` that cannot contain `const` in its constructor over `StatefulWidget` that does not call `setState`.

For an example: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2531761

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

After constant profiling and messing around, I came to the conclusion that there's no distinct difference between the two methods. For stylistic purposes, it's better to use a `StatefulWidget` whenever a hoisted non-constant variable needs to be used.